# RC snubber on mains connected bridge rectifier

Tags: diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, bridge-rectifier, snubber

I am designing a SMPS (90-230V) that has a bridge rectifier connected to the mains (of course after x2 capacitor and common mode choke).

We need this SMPS not to pollute with noise the mains , so we are thinking about using RC snubbers across each diode (in the bridge rectifier) . The diodes have a capacitance of 70pf.

We are thinking about choosing the C (of RC snubber) of about 140pf. My question is...at what voltage rating should I chose this capacitor ? Should it be X2 rated ? Can we use ceramic or needs to be film.

Comment: XY problem! How did you come to the conclusion that the mains rectifier diodes are the source of your (measued) EMI?

Comment: This is not how to deal with rectification noise.

Comment: We have 330uH inductors on both the ground and line between the mosfet and bridge rectifier(+ RC snubber across the mosfet that works very well). We just want to mitigate the noise from bridge rectifier.